# How to apply a filter within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array being returned, and currently I am showing all the users along with all their permissions whether they are `true` or `false`.

```
$scope.users.tst = 
[
'Mark', {Permissions{'Checked':true, 'Name': Add}, {'Checked': true, 'Name': Edit},{'Checked': true, 'Name': Update}},
'Andy', {Permissions{'Checked':false, 'Name': Add}, {'Checked': false, 'Name': Edit},{'Checked': false, 'Name': Update},
'Stephan', {Permissions{'Checked':false, 'Name': Add}, {'Checked': false, 'Name': Edit},{'Checked': false, 'Name': Update}
]
```

**Current Angular Code**

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users.tst">
 // code stuff
</tr>
```

**My Requirement:**

I would like to apply a filter within above ng-repeat to show only users having `Checked value True`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post proper structure of your $scope.users.tst.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users.tst | filter: { user.Checked == true }">
     // code stuff
</tr>
```

Documentation for AngularJS filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Checked is nested in 'Permission' object and 'user' is just pointing to 'user.tst' so are u sure it will work? did u get my point?

Comment: @immirza was just looking at that, how does a single user object look in the console?

Comment: '$scope.users.tst' is an array and it has few properties and array 'Permssions'.. So , under Permissions array it has 3 objects ... each object represent a user.

Comment: Yeah, got that. But how does one user look when you do a `console.log`. From this, i'm not sure how to access a single permissions item.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the structure of your object is very clear...

But as a psudo answer, it would be along the lines of:

true:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users.tst | filter: { user.Checked }">
    // code stuff
</tr>
```

false:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users.tst | filter: { !user.Checked }">
    // code stuff
</tr>
```

But as mentioned, Checked is nested so you should clean that up first.

Comment: So how is this different from my (also incomplete) answer except for the exclusion of the `== true`?

Comment: @Peter - edit made, false needed !user.Checked - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: OP only asked for when it's true though, so I don't see the value in that check. And like my answer it's still incomplete because of the structure of the nested items being unclear.

Comment: @Peter - Stackoverflow is not about JUST answering questions. Its a community to help EDUCATE people. There is no harm is demonstrating a simple true and false example that could prove useful to the OP in the future.

Comment: Hi, i dont think i can apply filter with my complex data structure, but anyways thanks for sharing explanations. I am probably going to put this logic in controller. So, i am marking answer correct for Peter since he answered based on my Pseducode. thanks again

Comment: @OamPsy I wasn't trying to invalidate your efforts or anything, just trying to come to a satisfying answer for OP.

Comment: @immirza - thats fine, im not concerned about points - happy you learn't something either way. Angular is a great framework once you've got your head around it :)